# Jenkins SoapUI Request isn't received Global Properties when it is run in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, soapui

I'm configuring a job which can run weekly.

```
c:
cd C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.4.0\bin
testrunner.bat  -c"articleRequest" "D:\projects\test\soapui-test\testing-soapui-project.xml"
```

Above is my command line block, which I put in Jenkins job. When I run it in Jenkins, the Global Properties parameter cannot be passed in the request.

```
    <subject>
       <party>
            <key id="${#Global#companyNoID}" source="T"/>
            <company/>
        </party>
```

And the result after a run with Jenkins

```
    <subject>
        <party>
            <key id="" source="T"/>
            <company/>
        </party>
```

Note: Currently, I host my Jenkins at Local Machine, and my above block command is run fine in window cmd.

Please advise

Comment: How are you setting your global property to start with: in the Preferences dialog or by passing a `-Gproperty.name=value` into `testrunner.bat`?

Comment: My global property is in Preferences dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global properties are saved in your soapUI settings file, typically called `soapui-settings.xml` in your home directory, rather than in your project file. So, you have a couple of options:

- Refer to your settings file using the `-t <arg>` argument for `testrunner.bat`. You'd have to copy `soapui-settings.xml` to your Jenkins box along with your project file.
- Pass your global property on the `testrunner.bat` command-line call using a `-Gproperty.name=value` option.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I've run with option 1 and it's run perfectly

Comment: Good to hear. If it's worked OK, accept and upvote the answer so others know as well.

Comment: I did, but my reputation is less than 15, so it's not displayed publicly

Comment: No worries. You should still be able to accept the question. It should look something like a green tick